# EF Core 'The DbFunction 'ÉmpContext.fnGetEmployeeEligibility' has an invalid return type 'ÉmpMaster'' while calling table-valued function

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, user-defined-functions

I have a table-valued function in SQL Server `fnGetEmployeeEligibility` which takes in `EmpId` and based upon some calculations it returns a result set with these columns:

- `EmpId` (`int`)
- `IsEligibleForPromotion` (`bit`)
- `IsEligibleForHike` (`bit`)
- `IsEligibleForRelocation` (`bit`)
- `IsEligibleForRemote` (`bit`)
- `IsEligibleForSuperWallet` (`bit`)

The SQL function is working fine and I have tested it. Now O need to call this function in my application and I am using EF Core

This is throwing an error:

> The DbFunction 'ÉmpContext.fnGetEmployeeEligibility' has an invalid return type 'ÉmpMaster'. Ensure that the return type can be mapped by the current provider'

```
Public void CheckEligiblity(int empId)
{
    var result = _empContext.fnGetEmployeeEligibility(empId);
}
```

In my `EmpContext` class

```
[DBFunction("fnGetEmployeeEligibility","emp")]
Public EmpMaster fnGetEmployeeEligibility(int empId)
{
    EmpMaster empM = new EmpMaster();
    return empM;
}
```

I have created a custom class `EmpMaster` which has the properties that map the function `fnGetEmployeeEligibility`:

```
Public Class EmpMaster
{
    Public int EmpId { get; set; }
    Public bool IsEligibleForPromotion { get; set; }
    Public bool IsEligibleForHike { get; set; }
    Public bool IsEligibleForRelocation { get; set; }
    Public bool IsEligibleForRemote { get; set; }
    Public bool IsEligibleForSuperWallet { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931594/ef-core-3-dbfunction-iqueryable-return-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Table Valued Functions as first class citizens was added in EF Core 5.0.

Table Valued Functions can be mapped to functions which return IQueryable and can now be fully composed over in your linq queries.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#table-valued-functions

Comment: How to map custom DB table type directly to .NET type, without actual table involved? Let's say I want to return lookup data for ANY table (defined by input parameter TABLE_NAME to my custom DB function): ID, DISPLAY_NAME, DESCRIPTION. I've created Oracle type and want to get IEnumerable list of lookup objects in .NET...